# Recursion Append list

Tags: recursion, prolog, append

Heres a snippet:

```
translate("a", "4").
translate("m", "/\\/\\").

tol33t([], []).
tol33t([Upper|UpperTail], [Lower|LowerTail]) :-
    translate([Upper], [Lower]),
    tol33t(UpperTail, LowerTail).
```

Basically what i want to do is look up in the table for a letter and then get that letter and add it to the new list.

What i have works if its a character, but I'm not sure how to append the new list of characters with the old.

Example input:

l33t("was", L).
It will be put through like this:
l33t([119,97,115], L).

Now that should come back as:
[92,47,92,47]++[52]++[53] or [92,47,92,47,52,53]

Problem is i don't know how to append it like that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Consider these modifications to `tol33t/2`:

```
tol33t([], []).
tol33t([Code|Codes], Remainder) :-
    translate([Code], Translation), !,
    tol33t(Codes, Rest),
    append(Translation, Rest, Remainder).
tol33t([Code|Codes], [Code|Remainder]) :-
    tol33t(Codes, Remainder).
```

The first clause is the base case.

The second clause will succeed iff there is a translation for the current `Code` via `translate/2`, as a list of characters of arbitrary length (`Translation` - note you had `[Lower]` instead, which restricted results to lists of length 1 only). The cut (`!`) after the check for a code translation commits to finding the `Rest` of the solution recursively and then appends the `Translation` to the front, as the `Remainder` to return.

The third clause is executed iff there was no translation for the current `Code` (i.e., the call to `translate/2`) in the second clause. In this case, no translation for the `Code` means we just return it as is and compute the rest.

**EDIT:**

If you don't have cut (`!`), the second and third clauses can be combined to become:

```
tol33t([Code|Codes], Remainder) :-
    tol33t(Codes, Rest),
    (translate([Code], Translation) ->            
        append(Translation, Rest, Remainder)
    ;   Remainder = [Code|Rest]
    ).
```

This (unoptimized) version checks, at every `Code` in the character list, **if** there is a `translate/2` that suceeds; if so, the `Translation` is appended to the `Rest`, **else** the `Code` is passed through unchanged. Note that this has the same semantics as the implementation above, in that solutions are commited to (i.e., simulating a cut `!`) if the antecedent to `->` (`translate/2`) succeeds. Note that the cut in both implementations is strictly necessary; without it, the program will backtrack to find solutions where `Code` bindings are not translated where there exists an applicable `translate/2` clause.

Comment: I had done something pretty close to what you have there. Problem is i can't use the cut, so that's why i keep getting stuck

Comment: Actually this should be ok without the check to see if the translate even exists. Thanks!

Comment: Aha... if you can't use cut, you could use `->` instead. I'll add the code in an edit.